# Can an Inventor assembly be translated into a Revit project or family with Autodesk Forge?

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-designautomation

I need to translate Inventor assemblies (iam) in some cases into Revit projects (rvt) and in other cases into Revit families (rfa). Does anyone know if this is possible using either the Forge model derivative api or the Forge design automation api?

According to this page https://forge.autodesk.com/en/docs/model-derivative/v2/developers_guide/supported-translations/ it's not possible, but the page is a year old!

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The **ModelDerivative** API does not allow to export in `RVT` or `RFA`.

Using the **DesignAutomation** API you can run an Inventor add-in to do this translation.
Take a look at this link [Design Automation Inventor with Revit Core Engine](https://forge.autodesk.com/blog/revit-core-engine-now-available-design-automation-inventor)

You will find a demo of the Inventor assemblies translation into `RFA` and the GitHub link to the source code of this project.